# how to stop redirecting subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i don't have any files in subdomain,my problem is while entering the subdomain url it redirect to main domain..how can i stop this..

this is my main domain htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule service.html$ service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ about.php?pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cont/([^/]*)\.html$ contact-inner.php?tid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ contact-page.php?tid=$1&ona=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^about/([^/]*)\.html$ about-inner.php?oid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^service/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ service-page.php?oid=$1&ona=$2 [L]



ErrorDocument 404 https://localhost/ezhil/path/public_html/error.php

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 117.202.102.84
deny from 58.68.25.210

deny from 91.200.13.112
deny from 86.128.130.170
deny from 91.200.13.7
deny from 173.208.206.90
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's your `ErrorDocument` rule.

Comment: Are `DocumentRoot` same for both domains? Try commenting out `ErrorDocument` line.

Comment: @anubhava different document root only

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess also in sub domain then?

Comment: @anubhava there is only one htaccess..that is for main domain

Comment: I don't see any rule here redirecting to main domain. Do you know how sub domain is setup in `VirtualHost`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55827/discussion-between-ezhil-and-anubhava).